# Why does my program only read the file name when a double file extension is given in C?

Tags: c, file, file-handling

```
#include<stdio.h>                    //standard input output library
#include<stdlib.h>

void main()
{
    FILE  *fp ;                      //fp is the file pointer
    char  ch ;                      //a variable to print contents of the file
    fp = fopen ( "text.txt", "r" ) ;//Normal file name with extension
    while ( 1 )
    {
    ch = fgetc(fp) ;
    if (ch == EOF)                     //if program reaches, EOF, it stops
        break ;
    printf ( "%c", ch);
    }
    fclose ( fp );
}
```

The program above does not read my file, but when I replace the file name as shown below, it works.

fp = fopen ( "text.txt.txt", "r" ) ;//Double file extension name

Why does **text.txt** not work but **text.txt.txt** work ?

Comment: Maybe because the file "text.txt.txt" exists and "text.txt" does not in the working directory?

Comment: Unrelated: If you are going to make programs that works, _test_ that what you order the program to do actually works. `fp = fopen ( "text.txt", "r" );` _may_ result in `fp == NULL` you know. All that. Test test test.

Comment: `main` returns `int`, not `void`. `fgetc` returns `int`, not `char`, so that the value `EOF` can be distinguished from any valid character value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This surely means that your file is actually named `text.txt.txt`.

I surmise that your file browser is configured to hide the file extension: if the file were named `text.txt`, then your file browser would presumably show just `text`, and since it's named `text.txt.txt`, your file browser displays `text.txt`. (If I'm not mistaken, this configuration is the default in Windows Explorer in all recent versions of Windows, so I'm guessing that's what you're using; but it wouldn't surprise me if there are other file browsers that can be configured this way.)

Comment: And I am absolutely astonished that this dangerous behavior is still the default in Windows.